# Zero flagged messages in chat

Tags: support, flags, chat

What's the meaning of icon with zero flagged messages in chat?

> [image: 0 flags]

It happens occasionally, not permanent. In normal case there is no icon at all.

Comment: no repro on chat.se

Comment: @redhand it happens occasionally, not permanent.

Comment: you could have mention that too

Comment: Users with enough points help moderator in chat, and as  such these flags are brought to their attention. This is done via the icon you high-light. A number will indicate the number of open flags; clicking on it will show the actual flags. Usually if there are none just nothing is shown. I suspect the situation you ask about occurs when a flag is raised and then dealt with before you check it out. (I am not sure if this answers you question or if you knew this anyway and only want to know the details in the last phrase which I'd not know either.)

Comment: Does the icon with 0 go away when you reload? That's very crucial to know. (If it does, the bug is with the AJAX check of flags, if not, it's something server side.)